# How can we resolve : "the method insert(DBObject[]) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (BasicDBObject)?

Tags: java, mongodb

Im using Mongodb with java and im trying to create a document :

```
// mongo-java-driver-2.10.1 version
// create a document to store key and value
            BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
            document.put("name", "Yassine LD");

            BasicDBObject documentDetail = new BasicDBObject();
            documentDetail.put("addressLine1", "Sweet Home");
            documentDetail.put("addressLine2", "New Street");
            documentDetail.put("addressLine3", "CASABLANCA, MOROCCO");

            document.put("address", documentDetail);

            table.insert(document);
```

I got this error : The method insert(DBObject[]) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (BasicDBObject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `insert` method expects an array of `DBObject`. Assuming `BasicDBObject` is a sub-class of `DBObject`, you can write :

```
table.insert(new DBObject[] {document});
```